# Change boot image on Yocto using Toaster

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, raspberry-pi3, yocto, boot

I'm fairly new to Linux and just started building custom images for raspberry pi recently, so I decided to use Toaster for image customization and building (probably a mistake). I've tried following multiple tutorials, by generating my own .h file from my image and replacing the default one in poky/meta/recipes-core/psplash/files, then running `bitbake psplash` and building the whole image, but it doesn't seem to change. I'm able to run psplash to see the [default Yocto project logo](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8.2/yocto-project-qs/figures/yocto-project-transp.png) though.
I'm using the poky distro and Toaster to build/customize the images. My custom image is based on core-image-minimal for this task, since it builds quickly. These are the layers I'm currently using:

```
openembedded-core
meta-poky
meta-yocto-bsp
meta-oe
meta-raspberrypi
toaster-custom-images
```

Any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide more info what things you have tried ? also what are the errors you see ? you can look [this official documentation](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/toaster-manual/toaster-manual.html) for toaster for correct procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the response, making an .h image and moving it to the psplash/files folder works now that I moved away from Toaster ;)